# NextJS 14 appears to be caching API request data even when data has changed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm using NextJS 14.x, and have a simple /dashboard/page.tsx where I fetch data from an API. I would expect that when I change the message data I would be getting the updated response.  Even if I am fetching data from a remote URL (different server) the data still appears to be cached by NextJS which makes fetching data that changes impossible.

```
async function fetchdetails() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/public"
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    const responseBody = await response.json();
   
    console.log(responseBody);
    return responseBody;
  }
}
```

The API is under the /api/public folder (route.ts)

```
const data = {
  "message": "hello world!" 
}

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json(data)
}
```

What is the right strategy to make sure the data is never cached by the app?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way (versus a config) but adding noStore() to the fetch method did work.

```
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache';

async function fetchdetails() {
  noStore();
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/public"
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    const responseBody = await response.json();
   
    console.log(responseBody);
    return responseBody;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, NextJs always cache GET method. If you want opt-out caching, your API route need to use one of below:

1. Using the Request object with the GET method. Read more [Opting out of caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#opting-out-of-caching)

```
const data = {
  "message": "hello world!" }

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json(data)
}
```

2. Opt-out caching entire route, by using [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config)

```
const data = {
  "message": "hello world!" }

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json(data)
}
```

If you want more granular caching strategy, you can put `{ cache: 'no-store' }` in `fetch`, read more [Caching in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching).